# Uncaught FirebaseError: Messaging: This method is available in a Window context

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase service worker for web push notification. Currently, I am facing this error:

```
Uncaught FirebaseError: Messaging: This method is available in a Window context. (messaging/only-available-in-window).
```

I am using a website on my desktop to register the SW. How do I resolve this issue?

Error stack I'm getting in console.

```
browserErrorMessage: "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: ServiceWorker script evaluation failed"
code :"messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration"
message :"Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: ServiceWorker script evaluation failed (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)."
stack: "FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: ServiceWorker script evaluation failed (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).↵    at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.0/firebase.js:555:225"
__proto__: Error
```

Thank you

Answer (score 23):

This method should be there in the main javascript file, NOT in service worker. Service Worker works in the background.

```
    messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
      console.log("Message received. ", payload);
      // ...
    });
```

Comment: @kimberlee did you try this? Did it help?

Comment: Hi, I have this issue too. The messaging variable is defined in my service worker so I can't reference it in the main javascript file. Surely I don't need to initialize firebase twice (once in service worker and once in the web app)? Is there an elegant/efficent way to subscribe to messages in both foreground and background?

Comment: @MattAustin Did you manage to solve your problem? Also curious at the moment.

Comment: @Peter the following is working well for me to avoid initializing twice...
 
var fbase = !firebase.apps.length 
      ? firebase.initializeApp({
        'messagingSenderId': '<MY_ID>'
      }) 
      : firebase.app();
const messaging = fbase.messaging()

Answer (score 3):

Please keep the Line, it is very much required in the SW:

> const messaging = firebase.messaging();

The Issue is not Messaging itself, but most likely a part of it that is used in your SW which however is not supported in there.

Sadly I can't see your Code from the SW, but what was causing this issue for me was that I implemented the following to receive Messages, while the Website is in foreground:

```
messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log("Message received. ", payload);
  // ...
});
```

This however requires the window context and needs to be implemented in the actual website, not the SW. For me this caused the Error you described.

Try using [Firebases sample SW](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/messaging/firebase-messaging-sw.js). This is doing everything it needs to and allows you to receive Notifications in the Background.

If you want to share your SW code, we could have a look at it.

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because you might have added the following code in service worker file(firebase-messaging-sw.js) 
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

Remove it and see code works.

The above line should be added to index.html only.

Comment: That's wrong. Look at another answer (by PaulPaulsen)

Answer (score -2):

I was receiving a similar error. Updating my JavaScript to use the new server key rather than the legacy server key removed the error. To get the new key, go to Firebase Console --> Cloud Messaging. Note that the web app quick start on the Firebase console overview page still uses the legacy key.

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "<**newAPIKey**>",
    authDomain: "<domain>",
    databaseURL: "<databaseUrl>",
    projectId: "<id>",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "<SenderId>"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Comment: apiKey != cloud messaging server key. BTW, you should only need the `server id` not the `server key`